# "Too many re-renders" when setting a state variable to its current value

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

The React docs state that:

> If you set a state variable to its current value, React will skip re-rendering your component even without `memo`. You may still see your component function being called an extra time, but the result will be discarded.

[[link](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo#updating-a-memoized-component-using-state)]

I thought this meant that, in a component like the following:

```
const Component = memo(function () {
    const [foo, setFoo] = useState('x');

    setFoo(foo);     // no-op?

    return null;
});
```

that the `setFoo(foo)` statement wouldn't really do anything, since it's obviously setting `foo` to the value it already has, so React wouldn't trigger a new render.

However, when I try this out (in a Create React App project), I find that it results in this error:

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

In my testing, I've found that the same occurs both with and without `<React.StrictMode>`, both in development mode (`npm start`) and in production mode (`npm run build`), both with and without `memo`, both with `setFoo(foo)` and with `setFoo(val => val)`. And this occurred in a fresh Create React App project, so it can't be too specific to my setup.

Since the doc mentions that "You may still see your component function being called an extra time" (and in this case the extra time will re-call `setFoo`), I thought that maybe it's just that the error-message is a bit wrong and should say "Too many repeated calls to component function" instead of "Too many re-renders"; but no, I confirmed that if I track the number of calls and eventually stop re-calling `setFoo`, React renders what was returned from the *last* call to the component function, rather than what was returned from the *first* call, so even the doc's statement that "the result will be discarded" doesn't seem to be true.

What am I missing? Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: (Posting this as a self-answered question because it took me forever to figure out, and I figured others might benefit as well.)

Answer (score 1):

On a hunch, I tested what happens if I write `setTimeout(() => setFoo(foo), 10)` rather than `setFoo(foo)` — so that the state is set after a 10ms delay, rather than while the component function is actually running — and in that case, it did *not* trigger a new render. (In fact, it didn't even call the component function an extra time.)

So it seems that the statement in the documentation:

> If you set a state variable to its current value, React will skip re-rendering your component even without `memo`. You may still see your component function being called an extra time, but the result will be discarded.

simply doesn't apply if the state variable gets set during a call to the component function; in that case, it must be that React discards the in-progress render and triggers a new call, even if the state variable is being set to its current value.

(I will reserve comment on whether this behavior should be changed.)

Comment: Calling `setState()` in `render()` makes it possible for a component to produce infinite loops.

The `render()` function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify a component’s state. It returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser.

In this case, avoid using `setState()` here.

Comment: @JamshaidTariq: Thanks for your comment! I agree that *ideally* we shouldn't call the state-setter from inside the component function; but I think there are some situations where it's not unreasonable to do so.

Comment: why would you setState() at same level of `useState()`? I mean u can assign value in `useState()`

Comment: @JamshaidTariq: `useState(...)` only sets the *initial* value of the state variable; that is, it only sets the value during the *first* time the component function is called. On later calls, the argument is ignored.

Comment: yeah you are right. mamoizatioin has nothing to do wiith states as mentioned in the link you provided. It is only used to control renders when parent re-renders but props to child does not change.. if you create a function in `Greeting` component and call it on click and setting same state, you will see component will not re-render.... `const abc =()=> { setGreeting(greeting);  }`

Comment: @JamshaidTariq: Sorry, I don't understand the purpose of your last comment; I feel like this answer already explains that?

Answer (score 1):

This is mentioned in the documentation under a special use case for `useState`: [Storing information from previous renders](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#storing-information-from-previous-renders).

It is allowed to call a `setState` function during component rendering to immediately rerender the component with the new state. This can be used to display information based on the difference between the current state and previous state without requiring a less performant `useEffect`. This may seem surprising, but it is a valid pattern.

But see this warning from the documentation:

> Note that if you call a set function while rendering, it must be inside a condition like `prevCount !== count`, and there must be a call like `setPrevCount(count)` inside of the condition. Otherwise, your component would re-render in a loop until it crashes. Also, you can only update the state of the currently rendering component like this. Calling the `set` function of another component during rendering is an error.